# How to generate an object with additional properties body request in OpenAPI 3.0 Java generator

Tags: java, openapi, openapi-generator

I have OpenAPI descriptor of the service that has cofigurable path and it can have multiple parameters in body (just strings but it may have multiple or none in them):

```
openapi: "3.0.0"
paths:
  /{pagePath}:
    post:
      operationId: modifyWithPost
      parameters:
        - name: pagePath
          in: path
          required: true
          schema:
            type: string
      requestBody:
        required: true
        content:
          application/x-www-form-urlencoded:
            schema:
              type: object
              additionalProperties:
                type: string
      responses:
        '201':
          description: Page created
```

Unfortunately, it generates me API that has just path parameter, and I don't know how to send additional part of data in Java API:

```
public void modifyWithPost(String pagePath) throws ApiException {
    this.modifyWithPost(pagePath);
}
```

I have tried to create separated scheme also, but the exact result is generated. Moreover, even if I will provide separated schema and generate the model, it inlines all named parameter into methods. Is there a way to force the generator create an object that provides multiple different key-value pairs?

Comment: Try adding `type: object` to the body schema (as a sibling of `additionalProperties`). Does this help?

Comment: Good point, I tried this one as well, didn't mention in the question though. I will add the type to schema.

Comment: Do you use the latest version of openapi-generator?

Comment: @Helen, I am using 4.2.3 at the moment - seems like the latest-ish version.

Comment: However, I have changed to 4.3.1 and the same API is generated.